# Retrieve the DB connection string password from the Azure vault to web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

How can I Retrieve the password of my DB connection stored in Azure vault and use it in web.config
I want to pass the password from vault URL. Kindly suggest

```
<add name="TestConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestDataModel.csdl|res://*/TestDataModel.ssdl|res://*/TestDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=**********;initial catalog=*********;user id=**********;password=*********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Comment: do you want to deploy this in Azure App Service?

Comment: Yes I have asp.net application which I am deploying in Azure App Service

Comment: then take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: @silent I tried but didn't work for me. I am getting this error
    
 System.Exception: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: '@microsoft.keyvault(secreturi'. I am passing it in this way - <add name="TestConnection" connectionString="@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://***********)"

Comment: no, not like that. You will retrieve the secret as an entire app setting. Inside your app then use this app setting `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyAppSetting")` instead of your connectionstring method

Comment: @silent - can you give a small example of config and the code in app, thanks in advance !

Comment: You don't need to store your connection string in web.config in order to use it in your app.